# Selenium - Troubles when trying to use javascript-xpath instead of ajaxslt

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm currently trying to improve my Selenium tests on IE. I would like to use **javascript-xpath** instead of **ajaxslt**.

My setUp function is :

```
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
  super.setUp(host, browser);
  selenium.setSpeed(Constants.DELAY_BETWEEN_ACTIONS);
  selenium.windowMaximize();
  selenium.allowNativeXpath("false");
  selenium.useXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath");
 }
```

When I try to find an element by Xpath, for instance :

```
selenium.click("xpath=//a[@id='linkLogin']");
```

I get the error (only when i try to use **javascript-xpath**):

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]: //a[@id='linkLogin']

What do i miss to correctly use **javascript-xpath** ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing your locator strategy away from xpath?  I've been using a form of CSS locators that are on average 5 times faster than xpath.